# Pipe tail output via elinks

Tags: linux, bash

Consider the following command:

```
elinks -dump file.html
```

It will print the file, formatted as plain text (without HTML tags).

The file.html is constantly updated (a new data is appended) and I want to run it through "tail -f like this:

```
tail -f file.html | elinks -dump
```

However it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tail -n +1 -f file.html | while read line; do elinks -dump $line; done;
```

Try this one.

Comment: accepted with the following fix: tail -n +1 -f file.html | while read line; do echo $line | elinks -dump; done;